# Detect $.post() faliure

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page loads i have setup a jquery `$.post()`

```
$.post("area.php", {'user': $('#state').val()},
function(info){
      //do something
});
```

So upon load the php is called and is there a way to know if no `info` is received due connection failure or similar?

Comment: as a suggestion, consider using `$('#the-form').serialize()` instead of manually building POST data.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You just have to add a 2nd function to what you already have or use the promises like.

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
  alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```

From:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: $.post is just a shortcut for $.ajax which supplies the type="POST" part for you.  $.ajax also exposes the entirety of the method whereas $.post may not include all things.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$.post("area.php", { 'user': $('#state').val() }).done(function () {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
});
```